# Resolve promises inside setTimeout function in for-loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise, settimeout

I want to call web api at some interval through javascript/angular js 1.x. I have to do this because web api that I am calling restricts the number of calls per 300 second.

Please find below code that I am trying to make it work.
`RecordList` is list of objects that I need to pass with webapi call.
`setDelay` is function that adds the delay to each call with `setTimeout` function.

Inside the `setTimeout` function, I am calling webapi and it is creating the record successfully. I want a object or event or piece of code which gives me that all the records has been successfully created or not. That means how to know that all the promises inside the `setTimeout` function has been resolved or not. I know `Promise.all` and `$q.all` uses but they do not seem to be working with `setTimeout` function. Could you suggest something for this?

```
var waitInterval = 300;
var promiseArray = [];

function setDelay(obj, s) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var SomePromise = $http.post('odataURI', obj).then(function success(result) {
      //resolve(result);
    });
    promiseArray.push(SomePromise);
  }, waitInterval * s);
}
for (var s = 1; s <= RecordList.length; s++) {
  setDelay(RecordList[s - 1], s);
}
```

Comment: Is `'` in `odataURI'` typo?

Comment: Yes it was typo mistake, I have edited it.

Comment: "_they do not seem to be working with setTimeout function_". Of course setTimeout does not return a Promise. Have you tried `Promise.all(promiseArray)` ?

Comment: Actually promiseArray contains promise only for last inserted record in it. It doesn't retain all objects.

Comment: Any other code for this requirement would be also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to run the next promise after one finished.

```js
function post(n) {
  return Promise.resolve(n);
}

function setDelay(n, milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       post(n).then(function(res) {
        resolve(res);
      });
    }, milliseconds)
  })
}

function call(list, delay = 1000, index = 0, result = []) {
  setDelay(list[index], delay).then(
    function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      result.push(res);
      if (index == list.length - 1) {
        console.log('Result: ', result); // You can do something here
        return result;
      } else {
        return call(list, delay, index + 1, result);
      }
    }
  ); 
}

var RecordList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
call(RecordList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` `await` for the same

```
var waitInterval = 300;
var promiseArray = [];

async FunctionOfLoop() {
  var dataMain;
  for (var s = 1; s <= RecordList.length; s++) {
     dataMain = await setDelay(RecordList[s - 1], s); // here you will get the data after api consume successfully.
  }
}

function setDelay(obj, s) {
 return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(function() {
     var SomePromise = $http.post('odataURI', obj).then(function success(result) {
       resolve(result);
     });
    }, waitInterval * s);
 }); 
}
```

I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Without Recursion also its possible,

```js
var waitInterval = 300;
var promiseArray = [];
var tick =0;

function setDelay(obj, s) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var SomePromise = Promise.resolve(obj);
    SomePromise.then(function success(result) {
      tick ++;
      console.log(result);
      if ( tick === RecordList.length) {
          Promise.all(promiseArray).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
          });
      }
    });
    promiseArray.push(SomePromise);
  }, waitInterval * s);
}

var RecordList = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var s = 1; s <= RecordList.length; s++) {
  setDelay(RecordList[s - 1], s);
}
```